# Environment not breaking with the end of the page

Tags: environments, page-breaking, paragraphs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\scshape}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {2ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
  {1ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myquote}[1]{%
  \small\par\addvspace{3ex}
  \if@nobreak
    % we're at the start of a section
    % add the indent
    \if@afterindent\else\hspace*{\parindent}\fi
    % and instruct LaTeX to reset \@afterheading at the end
    \def\reset@nobreakatend{\@afterheading}%
  \else
    \def\reset@nobreakatend{}%
  \fi
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth -2\parindent\relax}%
    \def\myquoteauthorname{#1}%
  }{%
    \par\vspace{1ex}
    \noindent
    \hspace*{0.25\linewidth}%
      \rule{0.5\linewidth }{.4pt}
    \par\addvspace{1ex}
    \centering
    \textsc{\myquoteauthorname}\par\vspace{3ex}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\nobreak\reset@nobreakatend}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myquote}{---test}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{myquote}

\begin{myquote}{---test-2}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above MWE ([the code generously offered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549230/48787) by @egreg) the second `myquote` environment continues to overflow in the same page instead of breaking to the next page. How is it possible to edit the `myquote` environment so that it nicely breaks and continues in the next page. (Is it possible to have the option that if it is going to break, it shall start from the next page.)

Comment: it's a minipage, the main point of a minipage is that it is an unbreakable box

Comment: A breakable quote uses \leftskip and \rightskip for the margins.

Comment: @JohnKormylo or more idiomatic in latex \leftmargin and \rightmargin using trivlist, like `quote` environment