# Centering inside minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myquote}[1]{%
  % to change text size, say to small
  % add \small before \par in the next line
  \par\addvspace{2ex}
  \if@nobreak
    % we're at the start of a section
    % add the indent
    \if@afterindent\else\hspace*{\parindent}\fi
    % and instruct LaTeX to reset \@afterheading at the end
    \def\reset@nobreakatend{\@afterheading}%
  \else
    \def\reset@nobreakatend{}%
  \fi
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth -2\parindent\relax}%
    \def\myquoteauthorname{#1}%
  }{%
    \par\vspace{0.2ex}
    \noindent
    \hspace*{0.25\linewidth}%
      \rule{0.5\linewidth }{.4pt}
    \par\addvspace{1ex}
    \centering
    \textbf{\myquoteauthorname}\par\vspace{1ex}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\nobreak\reset@nobreakatend}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{myquote}{Diane Ravitch}
The person who knows ``how'' will always have a job. The person who knows ``why'' will always be his boss.
\end{myquote}


\begin{myquote}{Diane Ravitch}
\centering
The person who knows ``how'' will always have a job. The person who knows ``why'' will always be his boss.
\end{myquote}

\begin{myquote}{Diane Ravitch}
\begin{center}
    The person who knows ``how'' will always have a job. The person who knows ``why'' will always be his boss.
\end{center}
\end{myquote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[In the code above (original answer by @egreg)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549230/48787), I want to center the text inside the `minipage`. If I use `\centering` the rule moves; if I use `\begin{center}  \end{center}`, I get vertical space.

1. How can I center the text without moving the rule and not have extra vertical space?
2. How can have an alternate version of `myquote` where text is centered? (I tried to place `\centering` inside at various points, but in all of them the rule has also moved.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the easiest solution is to add an additional group which restricts the effect of whatever declaration you write in the environment body

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myquote}[1]{%
  % to change text size, say to small
  % add \small before \par in the next line
  \par\addvspace{2ex}
  \if@nobreak
    % we're at the start of a section
    % add the indent
    \if@afterindent\else\hspace*{\parindent}\fi
    % and instruct LaTeX to reset \@afterheading at the end
    \def\reset@nobreakatend{\@afterheading}%
  \else
    \def\reset@nobreakatend{}%
  \fi
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth -2\parindent\relax}%
    \def\myquoteauthorname{#1}%
    \begingroup   % <-- ADD THIS
  }{%
    \par\endgroup\vspace{0.2ex}  % <-- ADD \endgroup HERE
    \noindent
    \hspace*{0.25\linewidth}%
      \rule{0.5\linewidth }{.4pt}
    \par\addvspace{1ex}
    \centering
    \textbf{\myquoteauthorname}\par\vspace{1ex}
  \end{minipage}
  \par\nobreak\reset@nobreakatend}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{myquote}{Diane Ravitch}
\centering
The person who knows ``how'' will always have a job. The person who knows ``why'' will always be his boss.
\end{myquote}

\begin{myquote}{Diane Ravitch}
\itshape
The person who knows ``how'' will always have a job. The person who knows ``why'' will always be his boss.
\end{myquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]